# CRUD operation on my quick links in my sites user property using JSOM

Tags: 2013, javascript, spservices, user-profile-property, quick-links

I am trying to build user specific fav. links , which user can update , delete and add using JSOM. I did some investigation but seems QuickLinks are not accessible through JSOM. 
workaround 1: Create web service and then use it in JavaScript. This will not as I am looking for pure JSOM based approach.
Workaround 2 : Using SPServices for this which is failing for me

```
  $().SPServices({
            webURL: "https://abc.sharepoint.com",
            operation: "GetUserLinks",
            userAccountName: currentUserAccount,
            async: false,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {


                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xData.responseText);

                $(xmlDoc).find("QuickLinkData").each(function () {
                    var linkName = $(this).find("Name").text().trim();
                    var linkURL = $(this).find("Url").text();
                    arrLinks.push(linkName + "|" + linkURL);
                });

            }
        });
```

This isn't working. Have less experience in SPServices.

Is there any other alternative approach to achieve this functionality or is there any way I can do operations on quick links using JSOM

> P.S. It is quick links in my site not quick launch

.